# MS ACCESS - the query works through a query, and there is an error in the VBA. How to modify the query?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have written a query that is not executed in VBA code, but the same query works through a query in MS Access.  How do I modify it?

Code which is working:

```
SELECT SLO_portfele.P_nazwaPortfela from ((SLO_portfele INNER JOIN Ewidencje on SLO_portfele.ID_portfela = Ewidencje.ID_portfela) INNER JOIN KP_KartyProjektow on KP_KartyProjektow.ID_kartyProjektu = Ewidencje.ID_kartyProjektu) WHERE KP_KartyProjektow.KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu = "Generowanie CWU"
```

Code which is not working:

```
strSql = "SELECT SLO_portfele.P_nazwaPortfela from SLO_portfele INNER JOIN Ewidencje on SLO_portfele.ID_portfela = Ewidencje.ID_portfela INNER JOIN KP_KartyProjektow on KP_KartyProjektow.ID_kartyProjektu = Ewidencje.ID_kartyProjektu WHERE KP_KartyProjektow.KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu = '" & (krotkaNazwaProjektu) & "' "
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
przypisanie5 = rst!P_nazwaPortfela
rst.Close
```

However, this is strange, because another query in VBA works (similar):

```
strSql = "SELECT Ewidencje.E_dataPlanowaneZakonczenieProjektu from Ewidencje INNER JOIN KP_KartyProjektow on Ewidencje.ID_kartyProjektu = KP_KartyProjektow.ID_kartyProjektu WHERE KP_KartyProjektow.KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu = '" & (krotkaNazwaProjektu) & "' "
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
przypisanie2 = rst!E_dataPlanowaneZakonczenieProjektu
rst.Close
```

The mistake that comes up is..: This code generates a message error:

> Syntax error (no operator).

How do I process the query?

Comment: Is it possible that krotkaNazwaProjektu contains a `'`?

Comment: No, it's not possible. I tried the version:""" & (krotkaNazwaProjektu) & """ and it also does not work.

Comment: I don't see the usual code to loop through the recordset.  Just in case something like: dim przypisanie5 as something: rst.movefirst: do until rst.eof: przypisanie5 = rst!P_nazwaPortfela: rst.movenext: loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print the finished SQL:

```
strSql = "SELECT SLO_portfele.P_nazwaPortfela from SLO_portfele INNER JOIN Ewidencje on SLO_portfele.ID_portfela = Ewidencje.ID_portfela INNER JOIN KP_KartyProjektow on KP_KartyProjektow.ID_kartyProjektu = Ewidencje.ID_kartyProjektu WHERE KP_KartyProjektow.KP_krotkaNazwaProjektu = '" & (krotkaNazwaProjektu) & "' "
Debug.Print strSQL
```

Then open a new query and, in **SQL** view, copy-paste the content of strSQL.

Run the query and you will see why it is "not working".

Comment: I know what was wrong. I need to write: ((SLO_portfele INNER JOIN Ewidencje on SLO_portfele.ID_portfela = Ewidencje.ID_portfela) INNER JOIN KP_KartyProjektow on KP_KartyProjektow.ID_kartyProjektu = Ewidencje.ID_kartyProjektu)

But thanks anyway.